# write mathematical definition of functions

Tags: math-mode, formatting, function

Can someone help me write these 4 lines?

[image]

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: I suspect you are looking fot `\rightarrow`, `\longrightarrow` or `\mapsto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the `align*` environment. The lines will align on the character after the `&` symbol. The `\mapsto` arrow may be used also.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
T\colon\R^2 & \to\R^2\\
v & \mapsto T(v)\\
T^{-1}\colon\R^2 & \to\R^2\\
T(v) & \mapsto v
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're having difficulty coming up with the corresponding LaTex keywords for the symbols in your text, try using [this handy tool](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

It allows you to draw a symbol, then tells you which LaTex keywords may correspond to it. For example:

[image]